# Can D3js create graphs with clusters and edge routing?

Tags: d3.js

Similar to this example from the Graphviz gallery http://www.graphviz.org/content/cluster

Notice how the edge from a3 to a0 is curved.  Also, notice how the clusters are placed neatly in boxes side by side.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no layouts that come with D3 that would allow you to do exactly this, but as long as you're willing to implement it yourself, you can do basically anything with D3.